# jQuery UI tabs: how to place div with float:left property into tab?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, css-float

I use jQuery UI 1.8.16 for tabs.
I want to place in first tab few divs as columns (with `float:left` property).

But I can't do it correctly: looks like tabs don't want to work with float property in proper way (see image under the text).

There is code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
                <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;">
                    some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2"></div>
        <div id="tabs-3"></div>

</div>
```

How to fix that?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to [clear your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) in order for the container to compute the proper height:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; float: left;">
        some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>some text<br>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enTFQ/).